# Contentful NodeJs SDK, Client.getEntries | Load nested ContentType fields

Tags: node.js, contentful, contentful-api

I have the following structure

```
User {
   image: Asset
   ...
}

Comment {
   author: User
   ...
}

BlogArticle {
   slug: Text
   author: User
   comments: Comment[]
}
```

When I pull entries with the following method

```
const articles = await client.getEntries({ content_type: "BlogArticle" })
console.log(articles.entries.fields.comments)
```

I only get the sys property for the author

```
[
   {
      author: {
           sys: {
              ...
           }
           fields ??????
      }
   }
]
```

PS: This is the case for all types that come in second level of nesting

I checked the docs and the apis but with no luck

Any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a similar content model and was able to get the fields of the Author successfully. One thing you can do is use the `include` parameter. With the `include` parameter, your code should look as follow:

```js
const articles = await client.getEntries({ content_type: "BlogArticle", include: 2 })
console.log(articles.entries.fields.comments)
```

You can learn more about it [here](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/content-delivery-api/#/reference/links/retrieval-of-linked-items/query-entries/console/js)